# Finding a local normal form regarding distribution rank properties

Tags: differential-geometry, distribution-theory, vector-fields

I am working in geometry control field, fall last week on this exercice and I can't figure it out. I have a distribution $\mathscr{D}$ with $rank(\mathscr{D})=m+1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\leq 2m+1$. I know that there exists an involutive sub-distribution $\mathscr{L}\subset\mathscr{D}$ with rank $m$. I also know that the growth vector is $(m+1,n)$. (So I guess $\mathscr{D}+[\mathscr{D},\mathscr{D}]=T\mathbb{R}^n$, am I right?).

What I need is to find a local normal form $\varphi$ of $\mathscr{D}$ so that $\varphi_*\mathscr{D}=span\{f'_1,\dots,f'_n\}$ assuming $\mathscr{D}=span\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$.

So far, I guess I can use the fact that $\mathscr{F}$ is involutive to write it $\mathscr{F}=span\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}\}$ and then add a vector to build $\mathscr{D}$ but I don't know how. I guess Fröbenius can provide some help but can't find how. Someone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Reference: Article from Williams Pasillas and Witold Respondek (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004124)

Comment: Sorry, though my field of "expertise" is classical geometry, I am unable to help you. I take the opportunity to ask you to indicate a reference in order for me (and maybe also to others) to learn a little about these things...

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Here is a good reference I guess: Reference: Article from Williams Pasillas and Witold Respondek (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004124)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: Isn't stackoverflow.com a computer science related forum?

Comment: Very sorry. I meant https://mathoverflow.net/